# Get string value from Bokeh Multiselect

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, bokeh

My goal here was to create a Bokeh widgetbox which you could use to provide input to a form, however the only widgets that allow me to get my inputs back from Bokeh's javascript side into Python variables are RadioButtonGroups. Otherwise, Multiselect, AutocompleteInput, and others are ONLY able to return my input if it's in the form of an integer. This is being done in a Jupyter NB using Python and Bokeh 0.13.0, if you happen to have any questions or I've left anything out please don't hesitate to let me know.

Please see code below:

```
import os, time, sys
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import RadioButtonGroup, Button, TextInput
from bokeh.models.widgets.inputs import MultiSelect
from bokeh.models.widgets import AutocompleteInput
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets.markups import Div
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
output_notebook(resources=INLINE)


ipies=[str(i.strip('.ipynb')) for i in os.listdir() if i.endswith('.ipynb')]
minutes=0
hours=0
days=0
months=0
daysmonth=0
days=0

minute_options=[str(i) for i in range(1,60)]
minute_options.append("*")
minute_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(a=minute_options), code="""   
    var options=a;
    console.log(options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)]);
    var ind=options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)];
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('minutes='+ind+'');
""")
minute_rbg = RadioButtonGroup(
        labels=minute_options, callback=minute_callback, active=len(minute_options)-1)
min_title=Div(text="Which minute on the hour, * for every minute")

hour_options=[str(i) for i in range(24)]
hour_options.append("*")
hour_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(a=hour_options), code="""   
    var options=a;
    console.log(options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)]);
    var ind=options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)];
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('hours='+ind+'');
""")
hour_rbg = RadioButtonGroup(
        labels=hour_options,callback=hour_callback,active=len(hour_options)-1)
hour_title=Div(text="Which hour in a day, * for every hour")

day_month_options=[str(i) for i in range(1,32)]
day_month_options.append("*")
day_month_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(a=day_month_options), code="""   
    var options=a;
    console.log(options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)]);
    var ind=options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)];
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('daysmonth='+ind+'');
""")
day_month_rbg = RadioButtonGroup(
        labels=day_month_options,callback=day_month_callback,active=len(day_month_options)-1)
day_month_title=Div(text="Which day in a month, * for every day of the month")

month_options=[str(i) for i in range(1,13)]
month_options.append("*")
month_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(a=month_options), code="""   
    var options=a;
    console.log(options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)]);
    var ind=options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)];
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('months='+ind+'');
""")
month_rbg = RadioButtonGroup(
        labels=month_options, callback=month_callback,active=len(month_options)-1)
month_title=Div(text="Which month in a year, * for every month")

day_week_options=[str(i) for i in range(7)]
day_week_options.append("*")
day_week_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(a=day_week_options), code="""   
    var options=a;
    console.log(options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)]);
    var ind=options[parseInt(cb_obj.active)];
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('days='+ind+'');
""")
day_week_rbg = RadioButtonGroup(
        labels=day_week_options, callback=day_week_callback, active=len(day_week_options)-1)
days_week_title=Div(text="Which day in a week, * for every day of the week")
import pandas as pd
ipies_pd = pd.DataFrame({"a":ipies})
#Selection source: IPIES CDS
cds = ColumnDataSource(data=ipies_pd)

#Selection source: autocompleteinput & multiselect widgets
selection_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=cds), code="""
    // THIS CALLBACK ONLY BRINGS BACK SELECTIONS IF THEY ARE INTEGERS
    var cbobj = cb_obj.value;
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("auto_c_value = "\"+ cbobj + "\");
    """)
ms = MultiSelect(title="power", callback=selection_callback, options=ipies)
auto_c=AutocompleteInput(completions=ipies, height=100, callback=selection_callback)


button_callback = CustomJS(code="""
    var cur_index = IPython.notebook.get_selected_index()+1;
    var end_index=IPython.notebook.ncells();
    IPython.notebook.execute_cell_range(IPython.notebook.get_selected_index()+1, IPython.notebook.ncells());
""")
button = Button(label="button~!", button_type="primary", callback=button_callback)

w_box = widgetbox(min_title, minute_rbg, hour_title, hour_rbg, day_month_title, day_month_rbg,
                 month_title, month_rbg,days_week_title, day_week_rbg, button,
                  ms, auto_c, width=800, sizing_mode='scale_both')

show(w_box)
```